# why android support v4 fragment remains on next loaded activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Have loaded **activity A** and **frgment AF** on it, inflated in frameLayout element with id **"fragment_container_a"**. Have Button on **fragment AF** which executes code on click:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |     Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Then I need the **ActivityB** to be loaded with **fragment BF** on it.

Sometimes **Fragment AF** inflated on **Activity B** instead of **Fragment BF**. Why?

**Activity A** have fragmentContainer frameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
        a:id="@+id/fragment_container_a"
        a:layout_width="match_parent"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Activity B** have fragmentContainer frameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
            a:id="@+id/fragment_container_b"
            a:layout_width="match_parent"
            a:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I use SupportFragmentManager to inflate these support Fragments

Comment: lets see the code that loads the fragments in each activity

Comment: code used to load Fragment AF. Executes on ActivityA

`getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(containerViewId, fragment, fragmentTag)
                .addToBackStack(backStackStateName)
                .commit();`

Second fragment loading code from ActivityB
`getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container_b, fragmentBF, FragmentBF.TAG)
                .commit();`

http://pastebin.com/fF9RUZGh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found that fragment elemnent with link to Fragment AF class inside of Fragment BF class

```
 <fragment
        a:id="@+id/progressbarContainer"
        a:name="-=Fragment BF class=-"
        a:layout_width="wrap_content"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        a:visibility="gone" />
```